# I'm trying to set an int value using jLabel and the setText method

Tags: java, integer, settext

I'm trying to set an int value using jLabel and the setText method. But of course setText wants a String. How do I get round this? I'll give you a snippet of the code:

```
int value = 1;
if (this.crit.getValue() == 1.0D)
{
  value = 10 - ((int)(1.0D / this.crit.getValue()) + 1);
  this.lblUnten.setText((int)(1.0D / this.crit.getValue())+"");
  texts((int)(1.0D / this.crit.getValue()), this.lblUntenmitte);
}
if ((this.crit.getValue() < 1.0D))
{
  value = 10 - ((int)(1.0D / this.crit.getValue()) + 1);
  texts((int)(1.0D / this.crit.getValue()));
  texts((int)(1.0D / this.crit.getValue()), this.lblUntenlinks);
}
if (this.crit.getValue() > 1.0D)
{
  value = (int)this.crit.getValue() + 7;
  this.lblUnten.setText((int)this.crit.getValue());
  texts((int)this.crit.getValue(), this.lblUntenrechts);
}
this.scale.setSelection(value);
```

}

Comment: If one of these answers is a correct solution for your question, please mark it as "Answer" or close your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's actually fairly simple as you can just concatenate your `int` with an empty string or call the `toString()` method on your `int` after having it wrapped in the `Integer` class like below. It would look something like:

```
int yourNumber = 30;
yourLabel.setText(yourNumber + "");
```

or:

```
yourLabel.setText(new Integer(yourNumber).toString());
```

Comment: This is invalid code. You cannot call `toString()` on a primitive type like `int`. `toString()` can only be called on objects.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I forgot to wrap it in an `Integer`. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `int` to a `String`. You can use `String.valueOf(value)`:

```
int value = 10; // Your value
yourLabel.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your int into a **String**:

For example:

```java
int yourNumber = 10;

yourJLabel.setText(String.valueOf(yourNumber));
```